# What does the Asterisk * mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Is it true, that the Asterisk always means "Hey, that is a pointer!"
And an Pointer always holds an memory adress?

(Yes I know for the exception that a * is used for math operation)

For Example:

```
NSString* myString;
```

or

```
SomeClass* thatClass;
```

or

```
(*somePointerToAStruct).myStructComponent = 5;
```

I feel that there is more I need to know about the Asterirsk (*) than that I use it when defining an Variable that is a pointer to a class.

Because sometimes I already say in the declaration of an parameter that the Parameter variable is a pointer, and still I have to use the Asterisk in front of the Variable in order to access the value. That recently happened after I wanted to pass a pointer of an struct to a method in a way like [myObj myMethod:&myStruct], I could not access a component value from that structure even though my method declaration already said that there is a parameter (DemoStruct*)myVar which indeed should be already known as a pointer to that demostruct, still I had always to say: "Man, compiler. Listen! It IIISSS a pointer:" and write: (*myVar).myStructComponentX = 5;

I really really really do not understand why I have to say that twice. And only in this case.

When I use the Asterisk in context of an NSString* myString then I can just access myString however I like, without telling the compiler each time that it's a pointer. i.e. like using *myString = @"yep".

It just makes no sense to me.

Comment: This is actually a C question as it is not specific to Objective-C :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581657/why-do-i-have-to-write-mypointervar-only-sometimes-in-objective-c

Comment: what is specific to Objective-C is the notation @"..." for a string object. In Cocoa, the class of such string objects is NSString.

Comment: For other people who are new to Objective-C like me, this tutorial was really helpful in understanding the asterisk and other basics: [The Beginner’s Guide to Objective-C: Language and Variables](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-beginners-guide-to-objective-c-language-and-variables)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

an * is actually an operator to de-reference a pointer. The only time it means "hey i'm a pointer" is during variable declaration.

```
Foo* foo  // declare foo, a pointer to a Foo object
&foo      // the memory address of foo
*foo      // de-reference the pointer - gives the Foo object (value)
```

Comment: It doesn't mean anything different during declaration--`Foo* foo` is actually `Foo *foo`, as in, "`*foo` is a `Foo`". It's totally consistent.

Comment: Does it matter where you place asterisk during declaration? What is the good practice? (i.e. `Foo* foo` and `Foo *foo`)

Answer (score 4):

mmattax well covered the distinction between declaration (as a pointer) and dereferencing.

However, as to your point about:

```
  (*myVar).myStructComponentX = 5;
```

to access a member of an instance of a C struct (as this is) you can do what you did , or more commonly you use the `->` notation:

```
  myVar->myStructComponentX = 5;
```

Objective-C is a little confusing here because it recently (in ObjC 2.0) introduced *property syntax*, which is a short cut for:

```
  int val = [myObject someIntProperty];
```

and can now be written as:

```
  int val = myObject.someIntProperty;
```

This is Objective C (2.0) syntax for accessing a property which you have declared (not an actual member variable), whereas your example was accessing a member of a C struct.

Make sure you are clear on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [my answer of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581657/why-do-i-have-to-write-mypointervar-only-sometimes-in-objective-c/581669#581669), `@"yep"` is already a pointer, so there is no need of `*` before `myString` which is also a pointer. In this case, you assign pointers not values.